# Median of two sorted arrays JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, programming-challenge, complexity, median

Trying to find the median of two sorted arrays in O(log(m+n)) or better. I believe this is O(log(m+n) or O(log(m)) or O(n).

```js
var findMedianSortedArrays = function(nums1, nums2) {
  let ar = []
  let len = nums1.length + nums2.length
  let half;

  if (len % 2 === 0) {
    half = len / 2
  } else {
    half = Math.ceil(len / 2)
  }
  for (let i = 0, r1 = 0, r2 = 0; i <= len; i++) {
    if (r1 >= nums1.length || nums1[r1] > nums2[r2]) ar[i] = nums2[r2++]
    else ar[i] = nums1[r1++]
    if (!nums1[i] && nums1.length === r1) {
      ar = ar.concat(nums2.slice(r2))
      return median(ar, len)
    }
    if (!nums2[i] && nums2.length === r2) {
      ar = ar.concat(nums1.slice(r1))
      return median(ar, len)
    }
    if (half === i) {
      return median(ar, len)
    }
  }

  function median(arr, len) {
    if (len % 2 === 0) {
      let half = len / 2
      return median = (arr[half - 1] + arr[half]) / 2
    } else {
      let half = Math.ceil(len / 2)
      return median = arr[half - 1]
    }
  }
}

console.log(findMedianSortedArrays([1, 4], [2, 3, 5, 6]))
```

Comment: You are using `concat()`, so your implementation is at \$O(m)\$, or perhaps \$O(n)\$.

Comment: @AJNeufeld good point, I did not realize concat runs in O(n). Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

#### Unnecessary storage

The current implementation basically processes the two input arrays in parallel, taking the next smaller element from the appropriate array, and appending to `ar`,
until either the end of an input array is reached,
or the counter `i` reaches `half`.

- If the end of an input array was reached,
  the remaining elements of the other array are appended to `ar`.
  The size of `ar` becomes `len`.
- If the counter `i` reaches `half`, then nothing is appended to `ar`.
  At this point the size of `ar` is `half`.

Then, the `median` function doesn't actually pick the median of the array parameter,
but it computes a value based on the `len` parameter.

The `ar` array is unnecessary storage. In the end, only the `half`-th and possibly the `half + 1`-th values will be used.

The benefit of the `ar` storage is it makes it simple to compute the median in the case when the end of an input array was reached.
In this case, without `ar`, it's not trivial to find the correct index.

An alternative algorithm is possible without extra storage:
- pick values from the input arrays
- if we haven't reached yet either end, take the next smaller element
- otherwise, if we reached the end of the first array, take the next element from the second
- otherwise, if we reached the end of the second array, take the next element from the first
- before the above conditions, save the previously picked value in a variable

After counting until `half` elements, you can compute the value of the median based on `len`, `prev` and `current`.

Like this:

```
  for (let i = 0, r1 = 0, r2 = 0; i <= half; i++) {
    prev = current;
    if (r1 < nums1.length && r2 < nums2.length) {
      if (nums1[r1] < nums2[r2]) {
        current = nums1[r1++];
      } else {
        current = nums2[r2++];
      }
    } else if (r1 < nums1.length) {
      current = nums1[r1++];
    } else if (r2 < nums2.length) {
      current = nums2[r2++];
    }
  }

  if (prev === undefined) {
    return current;
  }

  if (len % 2 === 0) {
    return (prev + current) / 2;
  }
  return current;
```

#### Unnecessary computation

The `median` helper function recomputes `half`.
You could simply reuse the `half` variable that's already computed in the closure.

The loop condition `i <= len` is unnecessary.
It will always be true,
because the implementation in the loop body guarantees that `i` will never reach `len`.

#### Return value in case of empty input arrays

In case of empty input arrays,
the implementation returns `NaN`.
I'm not sure that's correct, or expected.
Unless the exercise specifies to return `NaN` in this case,
I think returning `undefined` makes more sense.